# Can't change the src of a image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

Im triying to change the source of a image with a js function but it seems to not work, the function executes on a mounted() of Framework7

This is what i have right now

HTML:

```
<div>
 <span> <img id="star_1" class="star" src="../assets/empty_star.png"> </span>
 <span> <img id="star_2" class="star" src="../assets/empty_star.png"> </span>
 <span> <img id="star_3" class="star" src="../assets/empty_star.png"> </span>
 <span> <img id="star_4" class="star" src="../assets/empty_star.png"> </span>
 <span> <img id="star_5" class="star" src="../assets/empty_star.png"> </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
setStars(){

 var full_star = '../assets/full_star.svg';

 document.getElementById('star_1').src = full_star;
 document.getElementById('star_2').src = full_star;
 document.getElementById('star_3').src = full_star;
 document.getElementById('star_4').src = full_star;                       
 document.getElementById('star_5').src = full_star;
}
```

This keeps me the empty stars and i wanna change them depending of a rating, how can i fix it?

[image: Image of what im getting right now]

I also tryed to get the document.getElementById in var but still does not work

Comment: Your `div` doesn't have a closing tag. check once.

Comment: one is png the other is svg. are you sure you have the correct extension?

Comment: @MohammedShahed that's  my bad coping the code im fixing it right now, tanks for saying it

Comment: does that solve the bug?

Comment: @MohammedShahed no because in my code div tag was closed, i just copied incorrectly

Comment: @chovy i got the img on png and svg, should it try it with the png one?

Comment: i would use one or the other but not mix them. as long as the paths are there however, it shouldj't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.star')
  .forEach(el => el.src = '/assets/full_star.svg'');
```

Comment: This worked, but i have question about this, there's some way to controll it? Because this gets all my stars to filled stars, if i got a puntuation of 2 out of 5 how can i make to just fill 2 stars?

Comment: I'm not a star patterns expert. But someone on here has asked this question before. You could probably do it with `nth-child)` selector though.

Comment: I tryed with document.getlementbyid().childNodes and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function isn't called an misses the "function" prefix.
The following code works:

```js
var full_star = '../assets/full_star.svg';

setStars();

function setStars(){

 document.getElementById('star_1').src = full_star;
 document.getElementById('star_2').src = full_star;
 document.getElementById('star_3').src = full_star;
 document.getElementById('star_4').src = full_star;                 
 document.getElementById('star_5').src = full_star;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <span> <img id="star_1" class="star" src="../assets/empty_star.png"> </span>
 <span> <img id="star_2" class="star" src="../assets/empty_star.png"> </span>
 <span> <img id="star_3" class="star" src="../assets/empty_star.png"> </span>
 <span> <img id="star_4" class="star" src="../assets/empty_star.png"> </span>
 <span> <img id="star_5" class="star" src="../assets/empty_star.png"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the method in the Framework7 methods() soo i dont really need to call it as function i just make this.setStars()

Comment: But thats obviously the problem. Because your Code works. The function isn't called

Comment: Btw you're not closing the div correctly. It should end with `</div>`, not `<div>`. This is a second bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @aggregate1166877 i fixed that, was my bad coping the code

Answer (score 0):

You should use IIFE Then

```js
;(function () {
const full_star = '../assets/full_star.svg';
const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.star')
stars.forEach((star) => {
      star.src = full_star

})

}());
```